# How do you change navbar-collapse height bootstrap 4?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a website with fullwidth & fullheight menu using bootstrap.

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a title="Home" href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a title="Home" href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a title="Home" href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I click the navbar-toggler the navbar-collapse collapse become collapse.show and briefly I saw a style="height:160px" and the it was gone.

How do I make it so that the navbar-collapse collapse.show become full height?

Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try overriding the .collapse.show rule in your custom css with height: 100vh ?

Comment: I did, but the result is that the menu animated twice. The first animation until the 160px, and then the second animation filling up the whole screen. I'm trying to make it only one animation.

Comment: That might be because of bootstrap's javascript method bound to the navbar .collapse. (juste tested it by myself) The best chance you have is maybe not using the bootstrap's scripts and create your own from scratch for that purpose.

Comment: It appears that is the only way. 

Thank you Pierre.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then I believe you can achieve this by putting another div within the navba-collapse div and target that when the screen is small to increase it height:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <dvi class="adjust-height">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a title="Home" href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a title="Home" href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a title="Home" href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  <div>
<div>
```

Adjust the height of the class "**adjust-height**" to what you want.